# iPhone 6 plus - App zoomed in

Tags: xcode, iphone-6-plus

I built my app for iPhone 6 plus on the iOS simulator. All the other sizes looked fine but the iPhone 6 plus was zoomed in for some reason. Why does this happen? Would this still happen when it is built to the Appstore ?

Note: I am using unity free version and would not be allowed to change the splash image.

Comment: Have you removed 'LaunchScreen' from your app ?

Comment: Actually, LaunchScreen is iOS way to figure out that app is developed for iPhone 6/6+ or not. If there is no LaunchScreen, application is treated as for iPhone 5/5s screen and it is opened in Zoomed mode by iOS.

Comment: I am not allowed to remove the launch screen from my app because I am using the free version of unity3D. @JitendraGandhi

Comment: Is there a way to create a iphone 6 plus supported splash screen with unity launch screen? @JitendraGandhi

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea about Unity.

Comment: Is the launch screen file set to your storyboard? That's what did it for me!